# instruction register Motorola 68k

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, program-counter, machine-instruction

Hello I was wondering how the program counter of the Motorola 68k is incremented as in Mc68k instructions are length variable. Furthermore what's the length of the instruction register? How can instruction register hold a length variable instruction?

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with the 68k, but generally the PC is not an index but rather a pointer to the start of the next instruction to be executed.

Comment: The chip knows how long each instruction is, and how many bytes to increment the PC by.  There isn't an explicit "instruction register".

Comment: yes but how does the cpu know how many byte to add to the current instruction address in order to point to the next instruction? In a fixed length (32 bits) instruction architecture it's easy as you can add a mux 2:1 where the input are register Y(used as the first data input) or 0x4(used in the microphase of Program Counter update). I'm sorry but I can't accept "the chip knows how long each instruction is..." that would result in a bad exam mark.

Comment: ok, let's generalize this problem to a CISC architecture. As you can read here
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/Program_Counter

"Each cycle the instruction decoder needs to determine the length of the instruction, in bytes, and it needs to output that value to the PC. The PC unit increments itself by the value received from the instruction decoder."

Ok, this is clear. But HOW the instruction decoder determines the length of the instruction in order to update PC correctly? I understand it's different from arch to arch but I guess there must be a general idea

Comment: It determines the length as part of the decoding process.  Instead of an "instruction register", the decoder has to look at a fetch buffer that may have extra bytes past the end of the current instruction.